# Trying to express a function with comprehension list, GHC attempts to make an enum of Doubles

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to express the following function:

```
gregoryleibnitz :: [Double]
gregoryleibnitz = map mul ( zipWith (/) (map num [0..]) (map den [0..]))
    where
        mul x = 4*x
        num x = (-1)^x
        den x = 2*x+1
```

into the same one using a comprehension list:

```
gregoryleibniz :: [Double]
gregoryleibniz = map mul ([x | n <- [0..], x <- (num n) / (den n)])
    where mul n = 4*n
          num n = (-1)^n
          den n = 2*n+1
```

However, the one using a comprehension list catches fire with the following errors:

```
ej3.hs:2:38: error:
    • No instance for (Enum [Double])
        arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘0 .. ’
    • In the expression: [0 .. ]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: n <- [0 .. ]
      In the second argument of ‘map’, namely
        ‘([x | n <- [0 .. ], x <- ((num n) / (den n))])’
  |
2 | gregoryleibnitz = map mul ([x | n <- [0..], x <- ((num n) / (den n))])
  |                                      ^^^^^

ej3.hs:2:39: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Double]) arising from the literal ‘0’
    • In the expression: 0
      In the expression: [0 .. ]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: n <- [0 .. ]
  |
2 | gregoryleibnitz = map mul ([x | n <- [0..], x <- ((num n) / (den n))])
  |                                       ^

ej3.hs:2:51: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional [Double]) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: ((num n) / (den n))
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- ((num n) / (den n))
      In the second argument of ‘map’, namely
        ‘([x | n <- [0 .. ], x <- ((num n) / (den n))])’
  |
2 | gregoryleibnitz = map mul ([x | n <- [0..], x <- ((num n) / (den n))])
  |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ej3.hs:2:52: error:
    • No instance for (Integral [Double]) arising from a use of ‘num’
    • In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(num n)’
      In the expression: ((num n) / (den n))
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- ((num n) / (den n))
  |
2 | gregoryleibnitz = map mul ([x | n <- [0..], x <- ((num n) / (den n))])
```

From what I can understand, GHC is attempting to make an Enum of Doubles...
If that is correct, how can I force it to be Integer?

Comment: your main issue (errors) is that you *pull* form `(num n) / (den n)` - try `map mul ([x | n <- [0..], let x = (num n) / (den n)])` instead - it's telling you that it does not know how `[Double]` can be a `Num` instance (notice the *list*) - that is because `x <- ...` will infer that `...` is some list

Comment: there will be another issue between `Fractional` and `Integral` there - I'd suggest something like this: `[ 4 * (-1)^n / (2 * fromIntegral n+1) | n <- [0..] ]` instead - this will yield `[4.0,-1.3333333333333333,0.8,-0.5714285714285714,0.4444444444444444, ...]`

Comment: Unrelated, but every time you write something like `(-1)^x`, global warming goes up a nanokelvin. Use `cycle [1, -1]`.

Comment: @Carsten Thank you! And there I thought a comprehension list would be simpler...

Comment: sadly to make use of `cycle` you are back to `zipWith` though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a list comprehension, a binding like `x <- foo` expects `foo` to be a list. But you wrote a single number there! Instead of `<-` binding, you can use `let`:

```
map mul [x | n <- [0..], let x = (num n) / (den n)]
```

or simply inline the definition of `x`:

```
map mul [(num n) / (den n) | n <- [0..]]
```

It's a little bit unusual to do a list comprehension *and* a `map`; instead of `map f [e | ...]`, consider `[f e | ...]`, so:

```
[mul ((num n) / (den n)) | n <- [0..]]
```

I'm not sure the names `mul`, `num`, `den` are actually doing anything to enlighten. I'd probably inline those, too.

```
[4 * ((-1)^n) / (2*n+1) | n <- [0..]]
```

Unfortunately, `(-1)^n` doesn't quite work out, because `(^)` expects its exponent to be `Integral` -- i.e. a type like `Int`, `Integer`, or `Word` that can't represent fractions. You could use `(**)` (check out the types of `(^)`, `(^^)`, and `(**)`, they're quite instructive) or use some variant of zipping:

```
[4 * ((-1)**n) / (2*n+1) | n <- [0..]]
[4 * sign / (2*n+1) | (n, sign) <- zip [0..] (cycle [1, -1])]
[4 * sign / (2*n+1) | n <- [0..] | sign <- cycle [1, -1]] -- with ParallelListComp
```

In the latter two cases, I'd be tempted to roll the `4*` into the `cycle`, as in:

```
[num / (2*n+1) | n <- [0..] | num <- cycle [4, -4]]
```

You could also consider modifying that first list to just have the denominators you care about in it in the first place:

```
[num / den | den <- [1,3..] | num <- cycle [4, -4]]
```

That said, after all that work to make it beautiful, it now looks so directly like a `zip` that I'd almost consider writing it as a list comprehension a mistake! Converting back to `zip`-land, we'd have:

```
zipWith (/) (cycle [4, -4]) [1,3..]
```

...and this is where I'd stop my refactoring.

Comment: Now that's instructive. Thank you :)